# Android hide action bar, status bar and navigation controls

Tags: android, landscape, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I am trying to make an activity that is completely fullscreen in landscape, and have the status bar and navigation buttons visible in portrait. 
I have to be able to do this programatically.

This is how I tried make the app go fullscreen.

```
private void hideNavigationAndStatusBars(){
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION); // these work only on API 21 and above

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

The problems are the following :

1. On some devices, I get a blank portion on the top of the screen, that is equal to the height of the status bar, even though the status bar is not showing
2. On other devices, the activity fills the whole screen, but when I click anything, the status bar and navigation bar appear, they resize the layout and it looks very ugly

What I am trying to achieve:

1. The activity should fill the whole screen in landscape, positioned behind the status bar and navigation bar, if they appear
2. When the user clicks on the screen, he/she should interact with the screen. Instead the first click displays the status and navigation bars and the interaction is possible only after this
3. The status bar should only appear when the user drags from the top

Answer (score 0):

to hide action bar call getActionBar().hide() method.

And to make activity full screen call 
this method
requestFeature(Window.FeatureNo_Title)

Answer (score 0):

Use immersive mode and system ui stable flag to achieve this. For more information please refer the document in developer site.